# Some help in understanding energy conservation relating to special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, conservation-laws, faster-than-light, tachyon

Consider the decay of particle $A$ into particles $B$ and $T$ where $T$ is the tachyon particle. The conservation of energy equation can thus be expressed as

$$m_A=\sqrt{p^2+m^2_B}-\sqrt{p^2-m^2_T}\,.$$

Note that $c=1$.

From the energy equation above, one can see that the minimum value of $p$ is $m_T$. However, how does one explain why when $p=m_T$, $\sqrt{m^2_B+m^2_T}>m_A$?

Comment: When you say that the minimum value of $p$ is $m_T$ what are you varying over? At the moment it seems like your equation fixes $p$ in terms of $m_A$, $m_B$ and $m_T$ so it has an exact value.

Comment: I am just looking at possible values that $p$ can take given the energy equation. If $p<m_T$, then the equation is not real, hence, I took the minimum value of $p$ as $m_T$.

Comment: $p$ can't take many possible values - it can take exactly one value - the one obtained by solving the equation so I still not sure what you are doing.

Comment: What, exactly, is $p$? The decay products might not have the same momentums. Also, tachyons cannot have a rest mass, so what is $m_T$?

Comment: @EricSmith Why do you say tachyons cannot have a rest mass? It can't ever be at rest, but it still has a so-called rest mass. Of course for tachyons this is a misnomer and should perhaps call it invariant mass instead. We use the same jargon when referring to the rest mass of a photon even though a photon can never be at rest.

Comment: A tachyon can have an invariant mass, but it is imaginary. I'm trying to get the OP to think carefully about what all the terms in their equations mean. In particular, what does it mean to compare $m_T$ (an imaginary number) with $p$ (presumably a real number).

Comment: @EricSmith - In OPs notation, $m_T$ is a perfectly real number. The squared mass of the tachyon in his notation is $- m_T^2$.